# I'm trying to install wine but an error shows up

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, wine

So when I paste this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

This error shows up:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.86.217 443]
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't know what to do about it. My Ubuntu version is 18.04.2 LTS

I tried but now it gave me a new error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 4.0~cosmic) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0~cosmic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is my [Sources List](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BHg3pQ5YXD/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine's repository for Disco isn't ready yet thus the error was thrown. To remove that repository, run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
```

Also, from your question and [sources.list](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BHg3pQ5YXD/), it seems that you are using bionic but somehow repository of Wine's Cosmic was added which will create dependency issues. Remove that also,

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ cosmic main'
```

Wine is present in Official repositories of Ubuntu too. To install that, run:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install wine-stable
```

Wine doesn't have any kind of front-end. It's just a background kinda app. Thus, it isn't listed in applications. But it is still there. You can check it by running any `.exe` Windows compatible program.

There are some front-end available in Software center of which I use PlayOnLinux. To install PlayOnLinux, run

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```